# Double clicking on icons doesn't respond well on a Mac

Tags: macos, mac, touchpad

I am a new MacBook Pro user and I am having a hard time opening programs on my desktop when I double click on the icon. I found out that if you go to *System Preferences -> Trackpad* and lower the tracking speed, the double click responds better.

However, when I do this the mouse pointer moves really slow.

Does anyone know of way to get the double click to work better without sacrificing the pointer speed?

Answer (score 3):

You can always manually adjust the double clicking speed.

#### OS X 10.7

The **Double Click Speed** option is under *System Preferences → Universal Access → Mouse & Trackpad*

#### OS X 10.6

The **Double Click Speed** option is under *System Preferences → Trackpad*.

[image]

Comment: Hi slhck, I am using Lion and there aren't any double click option settings there. With your help, I found that the double click settings are located under System Preferences -> Universal Access -> Mouse & Trackpad.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah, didn't know your OS X version. Added it to the answer. Thanks!